# Adding csp-html-webpack-plugin dosnt load my react webpage

Tags: reactjs, webpack, content-security-policy, react-app-rewired, customize-cra

I am using the npm ***react-app-rewired customize-cra csp-html-webpack-plugin*** to give my application more security following this example https://medium.com/@nrshahri/csp-cra-324dd83fe5ff

My config-overrides.js looks like this

```
const { override } = require("customize-cra");
const cspHtmlWebpackPlugin = require("csp-html-webpack-plugin");

const cspConfigPolicy = {
  "default-src": "'none'",
  "base-uri": "'self'",
  "object-src": "'none'",
  "script-src": ["'self'"],
  "style-src": ["'self'"]
};

function addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    config.plugins.push(new cspHtmlWebpackPlugin(cspConfigPolicy));
  }

  return config;
}

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin)
};
```

The problem is that when I try to enter the web page it does not load anything at all and when I check the console it shows me the following list of errors

[image]

Is there a better way to apply the security policies so that I can access the page without problems?

Thank you very much for your comments and suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The CSP in your config and the directives listed in the error messages doesn't match, this could likely mean that multiple CSPs are set. As content needs to pass all CSPs, you'll first need to identify and control all of them. Check response headers and meta tags for any policies.

You will need to add the font-src directive to you CSP based on the first error message. Expand the error to see which hosts names you need to add.

Comment: I did several tests and several changes in the configuration and managed to reduce the block list a bit, currently the configuration is this

const cspConfigPolicy = {
  "style-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
  "default-src": ["'self'"],
  "base-uri": "'self'",
  "object-src": "'none'",
  "script-src": [
    "'unsafe-inline'",
    "'https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js'"
  ]
};

Comment: and the block list looks like this

The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js''.

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-UqjdXRl56JFE7IpQ71vJ8w=='". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored

Cannot read property 'cssRules' of null

Refused to load the image 

What can i do ?

I can't see the webpage yet, only the favicon

Comment: You can allow hosts (unpkg.com), the path should not be included. The inline style violation could be due to a style attribute, which at least in CSP level 2 won't be covered by 'unsafe-inline' and needs to be rewritten.